# ways to authenticate a laravel web system

Tags: laravel, authentication

I am developing a web system in php using the laravel framework, I arrived at the part of authentication of users, where it is not allowed the type of user x access to page y. What is the best way to do this with laravel? I thought about creating a session and saving the id of the user, so every time he accesses a certain controller I check if he has access to the id or not. so I had some doubts.

- Is this a good way to perform this authentication?
- Is this really safe?
- is there any way for the client to change my session?
- What would be a better method for authenticating user access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel provides a very good authentication system out of the box. Even though Hacking is inevitable it provides very good protection and since Laravel is pretty popular framework you don't have to worry about the security part. if there is any security bug, patches will be available almost immediately.

And your second concern **can a client can change the session ?** the answer is NO, if you code it properly. session resides in the server unlike cookies, so there is no direct way for a user to change the session. if you follow good coding practices you are good to go.

And how do you **limit userA from accessing pageB**. This is a pretty common feature needed in almost all the applications. As of now Laravel does not provide an out of the box solution for this. but this is pretty simple, you can add a role column to the users table, and check whether user have appropriate permission in each page. Laravel keeps the user object in the session, and it is avilable via the `auth()` helper or `Auth` Facade. if you want a little sophisticated solution there is a package out there `[entrust][1]`. it seems a good choice.

**You may want to read about**

[Authorization](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authorization)

[Csrf Protection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/csrf)

[Authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication)

I hope I have addressed all your concerns

Comment: very good answer, I am creating this system and also a web service, do you think it wrong to use both the web service and my client page (that consumes the web service) in laravel? the two projects in laravel.

Comment: @Bruno it depends on the scenario. can't say without knowing the details, and if this solved your concerns, please mark it as accepeted answer

Answer (score 0):

Laravel provides a simple way to authorize action thats purpose built for what you need:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authorization